# Send 404 error code on forbidden directories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to send the 404 error code when users try to access forbidden directories. I have the 'deny from all' attched to all private directories, and the following errordocs on the main .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
ErrorDocument 403 /404/
```

This sends users to the custom 404 page I have set up, but when I check the request headers, it's still sending a 403 error code. Can I pass a 404 error code through the .htaccess file on forbidden directories?

[Copied over from stackoverflow]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not a straight answer, but if you have php [ or other server side include scripting ] installed - you can use:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
```

and in 404.php have:

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using RedirectMatch, like this:

```
RedirectMatch   404     ^/phpmyadmin(/.*)?$
RedirectMatch   404     ^/server-status(/.*)?$
```

but you sould write one line per resource to "hide"